# Is there such thing as AJAX loading too long?

Tags: php, ajax, find, cart

I want to have add to cart function as submit to my system however there is a problem with AJAX I think (I'm very new with PHP). This is part of the code in the cart.js:

```
$(".product-form").submit(function(e){
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
        button_content.html('Adding...'); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "manage_cart.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data: form_data
        }).done(function(data){         
            $("#cart-container").html(data.products);
            button_content.html('Add to Cart');             
        })
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Below is part of my index.php which I use to call this function as submit type "button":

```
<?php           
            $sql_query = "SELECT pizzaID, pizzaName, pizzaDesc, pizzaCode, Image, pizzaPrice FROM tbl_pizzas";  
            $resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
            ?>
            <li>
                <form class="product-form">
                    <h4><?php echo $row["pizzaName"]; ?></h4>
                    <div><img class="pizzaImage" src="local/<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>"></div>
                    <div>Price : <?php echo $currency; echo $row["pizzaPrice"]; ?></div>
                    <div><?php echo $row["pizzaDesc"]; ?></div>
                    <div class="product-box">

                        <div>
                            Qty :
                            <select name="product_qty">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>                  
                        <input name="pizzaCode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["pizzaCode"]; ?>">
                        <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

My problem is when I click the Add To Cart button, it remains as "Adding..." which you can see in manage_cart.php. Somehow, the part

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "manage_cart.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data: form_data
        }).done(function(data){         
            $("#cart-container").html(data.products);
            button_content.html('Add to Cart');             
        })
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

does not seem to be executed.

I have tried using session_write_close(); instead of session_start(); - as I searched on Google, they said probably my PHP take too long to load because of file lock or something - somehow it didn't work.

adding products to cart in manage_cart.php code is below:

```
# add products in cart 
if(isset($_POST["pizzaCode"])) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }   
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT pizzaName, pizzaPrice FROM tbl_pizzas WHERE pizzaCode=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $product['pizzaCode']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($pizzaName, $pizzaPrice);
    while($statement->fetch()){ 
        $product["pizzaName"] = $pizzaName;
        $product["pizzaPrice"] = $pizzaPrice;       
        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])){ 
            if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product['pizzaCode']])) {               
                $_SESSION["products"][$product['pizzaCode']]["product_qty"] = $_SESSION["products"][$product['pizzaCode']]["product_qty"] + $_POST["product_qty"];              
            } else {
                $_SESSION["products"][$product['pizzaCode']] = $product;
            }           
        } else {
            $_SESSION["products"][$product['pizzaCode']] = $product;
        }   
    }   
    $total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
    die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
}
```

EDIT: I'm sorry for the wrong naming. The part of the code of the jQuery calls for manage_cart.php is NOT in manage_cart.php, but it's in the javascript cart.js

2nd EDIT: Added the add products to cart code of manage_cart.php

Comment: So, manage_cart.php contains the jQuery code that calls manage_cart.php through ajax? That's odd... Also where is the returned JSON?

Comment: for my simple suggestion .Better build HTML in js instead of php. It will reduce  execution time .Your query faster then before

Comment: @prasanth - Why would building HTML with JS be "faster" than doing it with PHP?

Comment: Check your browsers console to see if you get any errors. Also check the network tab in your browsers development tools to see if the request was successful, or if you get any errors. Something tells me that you're getting some errors, which would result in your `done()`-promise never getting executed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `faster` means .if php build html element , Ajax loading time is more high.If we return with JSON format and build markup with in js its really ah faster one compare with php.*for eg:Simply run more then 200 row js and php*.You could see the differents in network panel in developer mode

Comment: What say server/php logs ? We need also to see the php code from manage_cart.php

Comment: @prasanth - Do you mean that when they make an Ajax request, they should rather return json than fully populated HTML? That I can agree with.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson .Yes you are correct.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `Is there such thing as AJAX loading too long?` i just give suggestion to OP.I don't know the php code of the OP

Comment: You still need to check your browsers console and network tab. We can't debug your code for you.